# Possible to send 0 ERC20 tokens using transferFrom, from any wallet without allowance?

Tags: transferfrom

I am seeing some [unusual transactions](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5b004b5c5beef389b35d73791374132e32309beac24f61b112235e1ac47d4393) on Etherscan where 0 USDT is being sent from wallets using the `transferFrom` ERC20 function - sending to an address that has not been given any allowance.

It seems that any address can initiate a `transferFrom` of 0 `ERC20 tokens` from any wallet, and that is a valid transaction.

So my question is:

**Can any wallet create a valid `transferFrom` transaction of 0 ERC20 tokens, without an allowance?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the transferFrom function checks for the _spendAllowance that checks that

```
require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: insufficient allowance");
```

so if you are transferring 0 token and you don't have any allowance, the check will pass.

So yes, you can 'transfer' 0 token, but you are just burning gas and not transferring anything.

Comment: Scammers are phishing people doing this

Comment: How so? What's the technique?

Comment: 1. Generate address with same starting 4 characters and end characters as victims address. 2. Send a 0 USDT transaction from attacker address to victim. 3. Victim naively selects incorrect address from etherscan when sending from exchange or metamask in a hurry